# How to sync OS X Reminders with Android?

Tags: macos, reminders, android, google

OS X Reminders doesn't sync with my Google Account although Calendar and Mails work OK.

How to sync OS X Reminders with Google (or GTask Android App) to have it Android device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an app called [Reminder For iCloud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=us.doplus.reminder) on Google Play, which I believe can meet your need. It can sync reminders of iCloud.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need, [iCloud Reminder Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tai.tran.calendar.free) I developed it, If you have any question, just ask me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain to link-only answers. We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Links can change over time and then we lose the question-answer context. See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review -

Comment: I try [iCloud Reminder Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tai.tran.calendar.free) and works perfectly

Comment: Thanks for mentioning you developed it. It looks like it would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X Reminders only syncs to iCloud.

At best you can publish your lists and look at them through a browser.

Answer (score 0):

A rather crude method: Use an applescript to export it to .ics on a regular basis, and ask it to put the output in your google drive folder. It will be available in Google Drive.